# How can I upload data from Arduino uno ethernet shield to mongodb Atlas

Tags: mongodb, arduino-uno, ethernet, mongodb-atlas, arduino-ide

I need help to upload data from sensor to mongodb atlas using arduino uno ethernet shield I was using this code and it can’t connect to mongodb atlas.
I was testing code with static values in currentReading & voltageReading

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

// Define your sensor pins
const int currentSensorPin = A0;
const int voltageSensorPin = A1;

// Initialize Ethernet
byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};
EthernetClient client;

// MongoDB cluster hostname
char hostname[] = "mongodb+srv://mongo:XXXXXXXXXX@cluster0.vkdjf70.mongodb.net"; // Change this to your cluster hostname

void setup() {
    Ethernet.begin(mac);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    // Initialize other setup routines
}

void loop() {
    // Read sensor values
    int currentReading = 21;
    int voltageReading = 220;

    // Calculate watt
    float watt = currentReading * voltageReading / 1000.0;

    // Create a JSON object to hold the data
    StaticJsonDocument<128> doc;
    doc["Timestamp"] = millis();
    doc["Current"] = currentReading;
    doc["Voltage"] = voltageReading;
    doc["Watt"] = watt;

    // Convert JSON to string
    String jsonString;
    serializeJson(doc, jsonString);

    // Send data to MongoDB 
    if (client.connect(hostname, 27017)) {
        client.println("POST /HEMS.HEMS1 HTTP/1.1");
        client.println("Host: " + String(hostname));
        client.println("Content-Type: application/json");
        client.print("Content-Length: ");
        client.println(jsonString.length());
        client.println();
        client.println(jsonString);
        client.flush(); // Flush the data
        // Read the response from the server
        while (client.connected()) {
            if (client.available()) {
                char c = client.read();
                Serial.print(c); // Print the response
            }
        }
        client.stop(); // Close the connection
        Serial.println("Data sent successfully!"); // Print success message
    } else {
        Serial.println("Error connecting to MongoDB!"); // Print error message
    }

    delay(1000);
}
```

and I’m sure make network access to 0.0.0.0/0.
(databasename : HEMS
collectionname: HEMS1)

Comment: MongoDB does't speak HTTP.  Does 'hostname' refer to a webserver that should be forwarding the data to MongoDB?